# Neo4j: query to find nodes with most relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find which movie has the most number of actors in it in my database.Here's what i came up with but it kept giving me blank.

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m, SIZE(()-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)) as actorCnt
MATCH (a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
RETURN m, a
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not wait long enough, because your query is trying to return all the actors for every movie.

This query should return a list of the actors for the (single) movie with the most actors:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m
ORDER BY SIZE(()-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)) DESC
LIMIT 1
RETURN m, [(a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)|a] AS actors
```

It orders the movies by descending number of actors, takes just the first one, and returns it and a list of all its actors.